# Rails backgroundRB plugin need to schedule it and queue to database for persistancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, queue, backgroundrb

**I'm trying to do the following:**

1. Run a Worker and a method within it every 15 minutes
2. Have a log of the job last runtime, in the database table
   bdrd_job_queue.

**What I've done:**

I have a schedule every 15 minutes in my backgroundRB.yml file

The method call has a `persistent_job.finish!` call, but it's not working,
because the `persistent_job` object is nil.

How can I ensure it's logged in the DB, but still automatically
scheduled from backgroundRB.yml?

Comment: From what I understand, I need to Queue it instead of scheduling it through my backgroundRB.yml file. However, this does not answer all my needs... any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do it.

The workaround is to schedule a task that will queue it to the database, scheduled to run right away.

In your worker ...

```
class NotificationWorker < BackgrounDRb::MetaWorker
  set_worker_name :notification_worker

  def create(args = nil)
  end

  def queue_notify_changes(args = nil)
    BdrbJobQueue.insert_job(:worker_name => 'notification_worker',
                            :worker_method => 'notify_new_changes_DAEMON',
                            :args => 'hello_world',
                            :scheduled_at => Time.now.utc,
                            :job_key => 'email_changes_notification_task')
  end
  def notify_new_changes_DAEMON
     #Do Incredibly cool stuff here
  end
```

In the config file backgroundrb.yml

```
--- 
:backgroundrb: 
  :ip: 0.0.0.0
  :port: 11006
  :environment: production
  :log: foreground
  :debug_log: true
  :persistent_disabled: false
  :persistent_delay: 10

:schedules:
  :notification_worker:
    :queue_notify_changes:
      :trigger_args: 0 0 0 * * *
```